# Document is empty ( lxml.etree.ParserError: Document is empty )

Tags: html, xml, html-parsing

What could be the cause of this error?

I think this is due to the incomplete page loading of the relevant web page. is it right?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/Project-RDkr7CyY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyquery/pyquery.py", line 57, in fromstring
    result = getattr(etree, meth)(context)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3213, in lxml.etree.fromstring
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1877, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1765, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1127, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 601, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 711, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 640, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 1
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Document is empty, line 1, column 1



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/ubuntu/services/Project/src/parser.py", line 9, in __init__
    self._parser = HTML(html=text)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/projects-RDkr7CyY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 421, in __init__
    element=PyQuery(html)('html') or PyQuery(f'<html>{html}</html>')('html'),
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/projects-RDkr7CyY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyquery/pyquery.py", line 217, in __init__
    elements = fromstring(context, self.parser)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/projects-RDkr7CyY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyquery/pyquery.py", line 61, in fromstring
    result = getattr(lxml.html, meth)(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/projects-RDkr7CyY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 876, in fromstring
    doc = document_fromstring(html, parser=parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/projects-RDkr7CyY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 765, in document_fromstring
    "Document is empty")
lxml.etree.ParserError: Document is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this was due to leading or trailing spaces but I did not manage to reproduce. `str.strip()` fixed "Document is empty" error:

```
html = html.strip()
dom = fromstring(html)
```